# Entity Framework and 0 to 1

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

I have the following class and table structure:

- A component can have 1 Person (PersonID)
- A component can have 1 Group (GroupID)
- A component can have 1 Person and 1 Group
- A Person always has a Component
- A Group always has a Component

  public class Component{
     public Person Person {get; set;}
     public Group Group { get; set; }
  }

  public class Person{
     public Component Component { get; set; }
  }

  public class Group{
     public Component Component { get; set; }
  }

And I map this structure in this way:

```
public ComponentMap()
{
    this.ToTable("Component")
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("ComponentID");
}

public GroupMap()
{
    this.ToTable("Group")
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("GroupID");
    this.HasRequired(x => x.Component)
        .WithOptional(x => x.Group);
}

public PersonMap()
{
    this.ToTable("Person")
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("GroupID");
    this.HasRequired(x => x.Component)
        .WithOptional(x => x.Person);
}
```

If I select a Group or Person the related Component is always fetched correctly but when I select a Component, the Group ID and Person ID are fetched using the Component ID and not the relative PersonID or GroupID. Where I can say that the Table Component has PersonID and GroupID? Inside the Component Map?

The tables are

```
**Component**
ComponentID
PersonID
GroupID

**Person**
PersonID

**Group**
GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I got to make this working correctly is the following Mapping

```
this.ToTable("Component")
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("PartyID");
this.HasRequired(x => x.Person)
    .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Component)
    .Map(cfg => cfg.MapKey("PersonID"));
this.HasRequired(x => x.Organization)
    .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Component)
    .Map(cfg => cfg.MapKey("OrganizationID"));
```

Adding Properties of type FK on an entity doesn't make any difference than mapping using strings, I think is also wrong because expose useless ID on my Domain objects

Answer (score -1):

If you define the FK as one of the properties in the class EF is smart enough to map it for you.  You need to follow the convention of using the property name and append 'Id' to the end of it.

```
public class Component
{ 
    public Person Person {get; set;} 
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public Group Group { get; set; } 
    public int GroupId {get;set;}
}

public class Person{ 
    public Component Component { get; set; } 
    public int ComponentId {get;set;}
}

public class Group
{ 
    public Component Component { get; set; } 
    public int ComponentId {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a reason you're doing the mapping manually instead of using migrations?

Comment: Yes I just though is ugly to expose the FK as properties cause in Nhibernate you don't do that but if this is the way in EF I will adapt to it 
Thank you

Comment: You don't need to, but if you do it does some things for you automatically.  Another nice thing that I use sometimes is if I have the Id, I can set the FK instead of the whole object.  That's really handy if you're serializing entities a lot.

Comment: I will try this cause the DB is 100% legacy but with OData I can hide these FK from the result

Comment: Adding Properties of type FK on an entity doesn't make any difference than mapping using strings, I think is also wrong because expose useless ID on my Domain objects

Comment: Having the FK as a property is far from useless, I often use the FK instead of an actual object.  There are times when I have the FK, but not an object, if you didn't expose the FK as a property you'd have to create the object even if you just want to create the relationship.